# View analytics for a specific device

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I'm doing a project in Unity that includes Firebase Analytics.
The project is an iOS App that is distributed to a small number of iPads across the country.
The client wants to be able to look at the analytics for each specific device in each area. 
Is there a way I can set an identifying name to each device that then reports to the analytics?

I've had a look into 'Set a user ID' but that requires the use of 'BigQuery' which I would have to pay for and would want to avoid incurring extra costs for the client

I basically just want to set a device name (e.g. Device001) which will then group all the relevant data under this variant.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can log custom events using method - Analytics.logEvent("Event NAME", parameters: ["Device_ID":"uniqueDeviceIDHere","DeviceName":"Device001"]).
Now in analytics DeviceName and Device_ID will be available as filters.